# Get header, image, and link URL of articles on another page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a news.html page with articles that are within an `<article id="postNUM" class="post">` where NUM is a different number for each, with an `<h4>` title of news article, an image `<img src="imageURL" class="postPic" />`.

On my main index page there is a gallery that should display the top 4 news articles (just the image and title, which are linked to news.html#postNUM).

I am very new at this, but I managed to get the top 4 complete posts and either just the top 4 `<h4>` tags or top 4 `<img>`.

What I need is to create a new `<div id="slideNUM"><a href="news.html#postNUM" ><img src="imageURL" /><div class="caption>title of article</div></a></div>`.

How can I get for each just the text of the `<h4>` without the `<h4></h4>` tags, just the src value of the `<img>` and the value of the id attribute of each article. For example postNUM.

here's the jQuery code I have on my index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentPost = 0;
var totalPosts = 4;
var slideNum = 1;

$.get('news.html', function(data){
    while(currentPost < totalPosts){
        var $newsPost = $(data).find("article.post");
        var articleID = $newsPost.get(currentPost).attr('id');
        var $newsTitle = $newsPost.get(currentPost).find("h4");
        var postPic = $newsPost.get(currentPost).find("img.postPic").attr('src');
        $('#printPosts').append('div id="slide'
            + slideNum
            + '"><a href="news.html#'
            + articleID
            + '"><img src="'
            + postPic
            + '" /><div class="caption">'
            + $newsTitle
            + '</div></a></div>');
        currentPost = currentPost + 1;
        slideNum = slideNum + 1;
    }
});
});
</script>
<div id="printPosts"></div>
```

I don't really know how to only get anchor's href value, image src value, and h4 text.

Comment: Img has a src as you rightly said. So that would be a start. Also the code you posted does not have a class on the image

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the image class. On the news.html page it has a class="postPic"

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on what the jquery methods you are already using do.

If you want to get a html attribute, you use the `.attr` method on a jquery object. So, for the attributes you are looking to get, you would use:

```
.attr('href')
```

This would return the value of the `href` of the url matched by the preceding selector.

For image src its just:

```
.attr('src')
```

Then for the text node of a html element, you can use:

```
.text()
```

Comment: In my code I did use `.attr('href')` and `.attr('src')`, but I seem to get an object returned instead of an element so that `.attr()` doesn't seem to work.  I have not used `.text()`. I will try that for the article title. Thanks!

Comment: You must be mistaken. The attr method returns a string. See the doc pages for more info: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Can I use it the way I did in my code after a `get()` or did I use it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get for each just the text of the  without the  tags

`jQuery.each()`

*A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.* **on** [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Given this markup:

```
<h4>1</h4>
<h4>2</h4>
<h4>3</h4>
<h4>4</h4>
```

This jQuery code:

```
$.each($('h4'), function(i, v) { console.log($(v).html()); });
```

Produces these messages:

```
1 
2
3
4
```